# Disable Information from Event Viewer

Tags: enterprise-library

Hi can you please help me , In event viewer, there are warning, information,error. i want to disable **information** in event viewer. I am using Microsoft enterprise library.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Do you want to prevent information messages from being logged to the event viewer or do you just want to filter out information messages from being displayed in the event viewer?  If you are using Enterprise Library then posting your config would help.

Answer (score 0):

To disable logging by severity see: [Enable/Disable Enterprise Library logging on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077696/enable-disable-enterprise-library-logging-on-production).

To disable Information messages for the "General" category then the configuration would look something like:

```
<categorySources>
    <add switchValue="Warning" name="General">
        <listeners>
            <add name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
    </add>
</categorySources>
```